# Top 2 items in a Jquery Mobile "collapsible-set" do not align on large screen

Tags: jquery-mobile

The top two items on this Collapsible-Set center themselves. Any ideas how to fix it? http://www.mobileagentapps.com/
The HTML is all the same so I assume it is somewhere deep in Jquery Mobile causing this. It looks fine on my phone. Just not on larger screens.  Notice I copied the first two items- once they are third in the list they look fine. So there is no confusion with Jquery-Mobile experts- I did add this line in the HTML to constrain and center everything on larger screens:

```
<div style="max-width:600px;margin: 0 auto;">
```

My issue is not related- the pageitems did the same before and after.

```
    <div data-role="collapsible-set">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="e" >
            <h3>Branded Mobile Apps</h3>
            <img src="phonesbig.png"/>
            <p>With the REcake system you get native mobile apps for iPhone, Android, and iPad. The apps are branded to you and make it super easy for your clients to contact you. Keeping prospects is always a challenge and having YOUR app on their phone really helps that!</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="e" >
            <h3>Branded Mobile Apps</h3>
            <img src="phonesbig.png"/>
            <p>With the REcake system you get native mobile apps for iPhone, Android, and iPad. The apps are branded to you and make it super easy for your clients to contact you. Keeping prospects is always a challenge and having YOUR app on their phone really helps that!</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="e">
            <h3>Lead Gen-Text, QR, and NFC</h3>
            <img src="daleresponse.png"/>
            <p>Text response is still the preferred method for mobile lead generation. Go ahead and try what the sign says and see what happens! Dale is an agent in Washington state and would love to hear from you. Our system allows these signs to be reusable- you just log in and change the MLS number and the sign works on the new property.  We can also show you how to get text leads from your print ads!  </p>
            <p>Our system also generates reusable QR codes that point to mobile property pages as well. These pages- like the one at <a href="http://rea.bz/kelly-6" target="new">rea.bz/kelly-6</a> give leads information about properties and also show them how to download your app.

        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="e">
            <h3>Agent Facebook App</h3>
            <img src="facebookapp.png"/>
            <p>Do you log into Facebook nearly every day? If so, then the REcake Facebook makes perfect sense for you. Your friends can stay right on Facebook and search for properties, contact you about the ones they like, save favorites, print flyers, map the properties, and more.</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="e">
            <h3>Agent Branded Mobile Web</h3>
            <img src="personal.png"/>
            <p>In addition to our apps we provide a growing number of mobile web features. For instance you get branded mobile property pages for every property in the MLS. You also get a personal agent page that allows people to contact you very easily- for instance- <a href="http://rea.bz/kelly" target="new">rea.bz/kelly</a> </p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="e">
            <h3>REcake Overview</h3>
            <p>We provide you the tools you need to really connect with your prospects and communicate with your clients. And we pride ourselves in not nickle and diming you. We would love to have you as part of our party. Cake was used by the Romans to seal a bond- so we'd love to work with you to help you sell real estate.</p>
            <ul>
            <li>$14- Facebook App Only.</li>
            <li>$24- Mobile apps and text response system.</li>
            <li>$34- Mobile apps, Facebook App, text response system, and more!</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="signup.html" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Sign Up Here</a>
            <p>Watch our overview video</p>
            <iframe width="200" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/o3i0mc70y-I?controls=0&showinfo=0&showsearch=0&modestbranding=1"></iframe>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the below div, which is placed before the `collapsible-set`. If you remove it, everything will look fine on desktop.

```
<div class="content-secondary"></div>
```

---

**Before**
[image: Before removing the div]

---

**After**
[image: After]